# svn COPY results in 400 Bad Request

Tags: apache, svn, ssl, mod-dav-svn

I use Apache (and mod_dav_svn) to access SVN-Repositories on my Server via https. Checking out the repositories and adding, deleting or editing files works flawlessly, but when I rename or copy a file, the server returns 400 Bad Request on commit.

Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ***

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/***.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/***.key

    <Location />
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /var/local/svn
            SVNListParentPath on
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Location>
    <LocationMatch /.+>
            AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/local/conf/access.authz
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Subversion repository"
            AuthUserFile /var/local/conf/.htpasswd
            require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Exact error message:

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: COPY of /***/!svn/bc/94/***: 400 Bad Request (https://***)
```

SVN Server:

```
$ svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
```

SVN Client used by my IDE (IntelliJ Idea 11):

```
Version: 1.7
Format: 29
```

Sadly I couldn't find any hints on the problem in the apache error log.
Any suggestions on what might fix this problem?

EDIT:
I noticed, that changing the config to

```
    <LocationMatch /.+>
            DAV svn
            AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/local/conf/access.authz
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Subversion repository"
            AuthUserFile /var/local/conf/.htpasswd
            require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>
```

fixes the problem and allows me to use svn copy, but when i try to update my local working directory now, I get this error:

```
svn: E190001: Unusable URI: it does not refer to this repository
svn: E175002: REPORT of '/.+/***/!svn/vcc/default': 500 Internal Server Error (***)
```

Error in apache error log:

```
[Thu Jan 23 18:00:18 2014] [error] [client 94.222.125.77] Could not parse 'src-path' URL.  [500, #190001]
[Thu Jan 23 18:00:18 2014] [error] [client 94.222.125.77] Unusable URI: it does not refer to this repository  [500, #190001]
```

Comment: What version of Subversion on the client and the server?

Comment: $ svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)

Working copy on my laptop is on Format 29 (higher format isn't supported by my IDE (IntelliJ Idea 11) yet)

Comment: You really shouldn't be using LocationMatch.  Just put everything in <Location />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first problem.

But after you changed the config your second issue is being caused by the `LocationMatch` having the `DAV svn` directive, since that's causing every path to be calculated as the root of the repository.

This config should work:

```
<Location />
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /var/local/svn
            SVNListParentPath on
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/local/conf/access.authz
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Subversion repository"
            AuthUserFile /var/local/conf/.htpasswd
            require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: I used this config some time ago. Unfortunately there seems to be a bug in mod_dav_svn preventing SVNListParentPath to work with AuthzSVNAccessFile. When I use the config above and access my server from my browser I don't get to see the list of available repositories anymore (HTTP Error 443 Forbidden)

Comment: We fixed that bug with 1.7.0, http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2753.  We no longer update 1.6.x so you probably should be running 1.7.x or 1.8.x on the server side.

Comment: Added the Wandisco repository, updated to 1.8.5 and it worked. Big thanks :)